# setting a permanent environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I am trying to permanently add an environment variable in ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.

I have tried many of the online solutions but none are working.

I have tried adding:

```
export PLINK_PATH=/usr/local/bin/plink-1.07-x86_64
export PLINK_PATH
export PATH=$PATH:PLINK_PATH
```

in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, and `~/.bash_profile`

and when I do

```
echo $PATH and printenv
```

it does not show the path I want.

I am logging into the computer over ssh, I am not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Any advice or help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks :)

Comment: Missing `$` in the last line: `export PATH="$PATH:$PLINK_PATH"`

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables for more help

Comment: You may also need to "source ~/.bashrc" for it to take effect.