# Setting permanent environment variables to run a folder with a self-compiled app

Tags: environment-variables

I'm new to Ubuntu (2 weeks trial & error) but quickly learning. I'm running Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) on Windows 10 Home edition with 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver). GUI working fine via LXDE and UBUNTU-DESKTOP up and running. All software and packages up to date as per standard repositories via synaptic.

I have installed CMAKE-GUI latest version and successfully compiled and installed with that program and the console an app "eccodes" latest version. Now I want to adjust my environment variables so I can run the latest version of this app, instead of the older version installed.

I have gone over related threads [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951376/setting-a-permanent-environment-variable) and [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089838/bashrc-vs-environment-for-setting-environment-variables) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951376/setting-a-permanent-environment-variable) and checked-out the official manual here; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables

So I added a .sh file in /etc/profile.d named "extra_parameters_Herman.sh"

And put in the line

export ECCODES_PATH=/tmp/build_eccodes.2.14.1

When I run printenv after logging off/on I get (snippet)

..
ECCODES_PATH=/tmp/build_eccodes.2.14.1
..

But my Ubuntu doesn't buy it. I'm still at eccodes version 2.6 instead of 2.14.
A screenshot of the target directory is included.

I have tried for a day now and got stuck. So any help is appreciated!

[screenshot eccodes folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5Ouf.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't buy it"? How are you running the app and/or the subsystem when it doesn't get this setting?

Comment: For what it's worth `/etc/profile.d` is for all shells, not just Bash, so you should not use `export variable=value` syntax. Instead, put just `variable=value` and then `export variable` on a separate line.

Comment: @triplee thanks for the super swift reply! The eccodes app works with console commands like: grib_copy infile.grb outfile.grb but could you please be more specific how to define the path using variable-value and export variable using an example? That would be much appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't seem to attempt to answer the question in my first comment. You should probably [edit] your question to explain how exactly you run those commands if not from within an environment where `printenv` does what you expected.

Comment: See [Where is `export var=value` not available?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193095/where-is-export-var-value-not-available)

Comment: Fair point on how to run the app. To test I just run the command grib_copy out_new.grb2 out_new6.grb and the out_new6.grb file got created as it should, thanks! But I'm still puzzled why synaptic shows the old version of the app and not the new version.

Comment: Synaptic (and `apt`, and `dpkg`) don't know about software that you install from source (unless you use something like `checkinstall` to create a local .deb package and install that)

Comment: @Steelddriver thanks for that disclaimer, I missed that info. My app works as it should but the package version info is not updated. Thanks both posters for the help. This can question be closed.